# Enable button when 4 minutes is remaining with settled Datetime

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I am using MvvmLight to develope WPF Application.I want to enabled button when 4 minute is remaining with the settled time.It should automatically enabled in UI.Should I use thread to continuously track difference of CurrentUTCtime and mytime ?If yes ,then How to use thread with this code ? Here is my code.

```
Datetime mytime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day,22,0,0)

public RelayCommand Open
{
    get 
    { 
        return Open?? (_open= new RelayCommand(ExecuteOpen, CanExecuteOpen)); 
    }

    private void ExecuteOpen()
    {
        _navigation.NavigationToSetBetsDialogue();
    }

    private bool CanExecuteOpen()
    {
        double? remainingMinutes = null;

        DateTime CurrentUTCtime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        remainingMinutes = mytime .Subtract(CurrentUTCtime).TotalMinutes;

        if (remainingMinutes <= 4)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DispatcherTimer:

```
        private DispatcherTimer _Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        private bool _CanExecute;

        private void StartTimer()
        {
            var mytime = new DateTime( DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 22, 0, 0 );

            var interval = DateTime.UtcNow - mytime - TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 4 );
            _Timer.Interval = interval;
            _Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }

        private void Timer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            _Timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
            _CanExecute = true;
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }

        public ICommand Open
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand( ExecuteOpen, () => _CanExecute ); }
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to use Timer.I want to check Difference(CurrentUTCtime-mytime) continuously using another thread.How can I implement that ?

Comment: this is exactly what a timer does, executes your code (time difference check in this case) periodically. There is no "continuous" concept in programming - especially in regards to UI

Answer (score 0):

well you can use can execute and check for elapsed time no need for separate thread as can execute will run on parallel anyway...

```
private DateTime _startTime;
private void StartCommandHandler(object obj)
    {
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

 private bool CanEnableButton(object arg)
    {
        return _startTime != DateTime.MinValue && DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startTime).Minutes >= 4;
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `BackgroundWorker`. First you need to inititalize worker:

```
        BackgroundWorker bgWrkr = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgWrkr.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWrkrDoWork);
        bgWrkr.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWrkrRunWorkerCompleted);
```

Then implement handlers for events. `DoWork`:

```
void bgWrkrDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (mytime.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes >= 4){ }
}
```

and `RunWorkerCompleted`:

```
void bgWrkrRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

And sure you have to start worker:

```
bgWrkr.RunWorkerAsync();
```

You can start it right after initializing.bgWrkr.RunWorkerAsync();